# Chaincode deployment from github.com results error: cannot find package

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am learning chaincode development on Bluemix.

I have chain code under subfolders as below:

```
src->github.com->username->LoyaltyProgram
                           MyWallet.go (Chaincode)
                         ->LoyaltyProgram->main->Airline
                           Airline.go (Chaincode)
```

I have a package `LoyaltyPkg.go` that is under the following folder and is imported in `Mywallet.go` and `Airline.go` chain code.

```
src->github.com->username->LoyaltyProgram->LoyaltyPkgUtil
```

I am able to deploy `MyWallet.go` on to Bluemix using the deploy spec. However, when I try to deploy the `Airline.go` chain code, I am getting the following error:

> cannot find package "github.com/jaibhavani/LoyaltyProgram/LoyaltyPkgUtil" in any of:
>
> OUT -     /opt/go/src/github.com/jaibhavani/LoyaltyProgram/LoyaltyPkgUtil (from $GOROOT)
>
> OUT -     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/jaibhavani/LoyaltyProgram/LoyaltyPkgUtil (from $GOPATH)"

The package is available on github.com under the above folder. I don't know why I am unable to deploy the `Airline.go` chaincode to Bluemix.

Please note, I am able to build `Airline.go` file locally with no errors.

Comment: what is this 'main' (folder?) in the path after Loyalty? There also seems to be an Airline folder that holds 'Airline.go' ? This is a different path structure than MyWallet, which you say is running.

Comment: @jai - Please see the comment so that the community can help address your question.

Comment: Yes. The main folder has sub folder Airline, which contains the Airline.go

Comment: is this issue still persists?